# Converting "&" to "&amp;" when passing data to third party API

Tags: php, special-characters, html-entities, authorize.net

I am passing billing information & transaction info to Authorize.net, where special characters are displaying as html entities.

Eg: Customer name: **Harries & Johns**

Displaying as **Harris `&amp;` Johns** in Authorize.net merchant panel. please suggest something how to handle these kind of special characters when passing to third party API.

Comment: http://docs.php.net/htmlspecialchars

Comment: It seems unlikely that Authorize.net would double-encode the html entities. Are you _sure_ that you don't pass `&amp;` instead of `&` to it?